# Error installing psychopy on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: software-installation, python3, pip, 22.10

I have been trying to get psychopy up and running on my Ubuntu 22.10 laptop, and I am repeatedly running into this error. I have tried several different python versions thanks to pyenv, but this exact error comes up every time. In fact, I am getting the same error when trying to install OpenSesame, which is based on psychopy. Any help debugging this will be highly appreciated.

[image: No Module named "attrdict"]

Comment: Just do `pip3 install attrdict`.  That should make it available and then you can install the other things that depend on it.  `wxPython` is being pulled in as a dependency, and it depends on `attrdict` but it isn't pulling it in as a dependency, so just install it normally with pip3 first.

Comment: Did that, but now I am getting yet another error "metadata-generation-failed". The psychopy installation document is woefully out of date.

Comment: I would surmise that the issue then lies in wxPython, perhaps it's out of date or broken.  wxPython's the underlying module that's failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for continued response. I am looking into possible workarounds.